# Matplotlib/Seaborn: Draw horizontal annotation subfigures/tracks using dataframe

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to create horizontal annotations, something analogous to this:
[image]
taken from [here](http://apierleoni.github.io/BioGraPy/tutorial.html#tutorial). The package which generates such annotation is itself based on matplotlib, but I would rather use the packages directly. It also makes it easier to stack subfigures which share same x axis.

This is different from the standard horizontal annotation since I essentially want to add another subplot containing the annotation. The ranges itself are defined by a dataframe containing start, end, color and the name of annotation. I believe horizontal bar-charts can be hacked to do so(something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31057341/floating-bar-chart)). But I'm not sure how it will look with dense annotations, like this: 
[image]

Is there a way to do something like this directly using matplotlib ?

Comment: If the package that produces the plot is based on matplotlib, then the answer to the question is for sure "yes". But to be honest, I have problems understanding what exactly you want to do. If this is about annotations, they can be created via `ax.annotate(...)`

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, what I'm trying to do is to create annotations  "separate" from the main plot. The bars(annotations) themselves are another subfigure together. I just checked and found out function matplotlib.pyplot.broken_barh() - should have searched better. Will give this a try and see how things turn out.